# Abstract Method and Classes in Login page in Android

Tags: java, android

I am currently following a tuorial on how to create a login page in android and though i have followed all the instructions, two classes in my MainActivity are giving me errors stating that i need to declare them abstract or they need to implement abstract methods. May you please help me.

```
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_FIRST_ACCESS = "firstaccess";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    uName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    passreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.passres);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);
    passreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PasswordReset.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }});
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (  ( !uName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !password.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                NetAsync(view);
            }
            else if ( ( !uName.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Enter Your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if ( ( !password.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Enter Your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Enter Your Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask
{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){
    /**
     * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
     **/
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){
        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessLogin().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }
}

private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String username,passwordtxt;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        uName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        username = uName.getText().toString();
        passwordtxt = password.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(username, passwordtxt);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    /**
                     * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                     **/
                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                    /**
                     *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                     **/
                    Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(upanel);
                    /**
                     * Close Login Screen
                     **/
                    finish();
                }else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void NetAsync(View view){
    new NetCheck().execute();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Your two methods 
`public void NetAsync(View view)`
and `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` are outside any classs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String username,passwordtxt;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(username, passwordtxt);
        return json;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks. sould i also do the same for the netCheck class?

Comment: Yes, modify it yourself; you've got there a boolean instead of a JSON object, you should be able solve it on your own now. If solved, accept my anwer.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And this:

```
public void NetAsync(View view){
    new NetCheck().execute();
}
```

in `ProcessLogin`

Comment: Tried that. Still same issue

Comment: The problems seem to be the methods in the NetCheck and ProcessLogin Classes. The merhods don't seem to be used